# Where does the "Shut Down Windows" dialog come from?

Tags: gina

I need to trap the "Shut Down Windows" dialog that appears when you press the power button in Windows XP.  I'm using a custom GINA to trap security and logon dialogs, but the "Shut Down Windows" dialog is not a GINA dialog.
What Windows mechanism creates this dialog and is there a "ginastub"-style solution to displaying my own dialog instead of the XP one?

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell how display own dialog. But i think dialog comes from 'shell32.dll' in system32 folder. I am saying it as i found the bg image of dialog box there. And on changing it works.